# adb -s <device_id> shell pm clear <package_name> - deletes the app from the emulator

Tags: android-emulator, adb

I am trying to clear app's data from several emulators, in a loop inside a bash script.
Doing so from the terminal indeed clears the app's data, but doing so from a bash script will also uninstall the app from the emulator and close the emulator's window (UI).
I don't want my app to be uninstalled as i need to test it.
Is there a reason that this command works differently when executed from terminal vs. when executed from bash script? When executing from a script against a real device it works perfectly as it should - clear the app's data without uninstalling the application from the device.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
When the emulator is open (with GUI) - the command will work as it should, that is clear the app's data.
When the emulator is open without GUI - the application will also get uninstalled.